# Java Collection - Reference

Tags: java-8

I have a `HashMap` that stores data from DB. Should the user necessarily create a reference to iterate?

```
Map<String, List<Employee>> **map** = Cache.getMap(key);

for( Map.Entry<String, List<Employee>> me: map.entrySet()){
```

Or:

```
for(Map<String, List<Employee>> me : Cache.getMap(key)){
```

Minimum of 20 threads will be hitting the Cache at any given point in time. Each caller will take about 500 ms to complete processing the data in the map.

That said, which is the better option of the above two - from GC and speed standpoints.

Or is there a better option than the above mentioned options?

Comment: Create the classes locally and take the metrics in your machine or your environments. Nothing is a replacement to a good exercise.

Comment: There is no such thing as “create a reference”. In the first variant, you are just introducing a variable to hold the reference which exists in either case. That has no impact on what the code does. Once you fix the wrong syntax of the second variant, the result will be identical.

Answer (score 0):

Whether you write

```
IterableOrArray all=expression;
for(ElementType element: all) {
    …
}
```

or

```
for(ElementType element: expression) {
    …
}
```

doesn’t make any difference as in both cases, `expression` will be evaluated only once at the beginning of the loop rather than in each iteration. In the case of an `Iterable`, it is even hard to imagine, how the resulting code could reevaluate the expression and tell the new `Iterator` to resume at the previous position of the old one.

If still in doubt, you can verify it with the following example program:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for(String s: getTheCollection()) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
static Iterable<String> getTheCollection() {
    System.out.println("getTheCollection() called");
    return () -> {
        System.out.println("iterator() called");
        return Stream.of("foo", "bar", "baz").iterator();
    };
}
```

or

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] array={ "foo", "bar", "baz" };
    for(String s: array) {
        System.out.println(s);
        // has no consequences:
        array=null;
    }
}
```

So since there is no difference at all, there are no differences from GC and speed standpoints either.